# Boostrap 4 post card seem different on my website

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I found a bootstrap 4 card snippet but when I integrate it to my WordPress plugin, it seem different from original form.I want to show posts as 3 column.

> However some posts hasn't any picture - can someone explain why? Also the gird form isnt equal to original form.

Original snippet:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/kzbzW

My website :
http://www.themeforest-deneme2.deniz-tasarim.site/2020/01/03/fhhfh/

My plugin codes:

( I didn't change in styles )

```
//paste
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $settings['post_type'],
    'author__in' => $settings['authors2'],
    'posts_per_page' => $settings['posts_per_page'],
    'orderby' => $settings['orderby'],
    'order' => $settings['order'],
);

echo'<div class="row">';
echo'<div class="col-md-12">';

$query = new \WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        //echo "<div style=background:blue> lsdkjf </div>";
       // get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'masonry' );
       // the_title();
        //the_content();
        ?>
<style>



    h1{
        text-align:center;
        margin-bottom:50px;
        margin-top:50px;
    }
    .blog-card-blog {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .blog-card {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    }
    .blog-card .blog-card-image {
        height: 60%;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        box-shadow: 0 16px 38px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56), 0 4px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    .blog-card .blog-card-image img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 6px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .blog-card .blog-table {
        padding: 15px 30px;
    }
    .blog-table {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .blog-category {
        position: relative;
        line-height: 0;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    .blog-text-success {
        color: #28a745!important;
    }
    .blog-card-blog .blog-card-caption {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .blog-card-caption {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: "Roboto Slab", "Times New Roman", serif;
    }
    .fa {
        display: inline-block;
        font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
        font-size: inherit;
        text-rendering: auto;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    .blog-card-caption, .blog-card-caption a {
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    p {
        color: #3C4857;
    }

    p {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    .blog-card .ftr {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .blog-card .ftr .author {
        color: #888;
    }

    .blog-card .ftr div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .blog-card .author .avatar {
        width: 36px;
        height: 36px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-right: 5px;blog-
    }
    .blog-card .ftr .stats {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .blog-card .ftr .stats {
        float: right;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

</style>
    <!-- <div class="col-md-2"> -->
        <div class="blog-card blog-card-blog">
            <div class="blog-card-image">
               <!--  <a href="#"> <img class="img" src=<?php //the_post_thumbnail(); ?>> </a> -->
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'img')); ?>
                <div class="ripple-cont"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-table">
                <h6 class="blog-category blog-text-success"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i> News</h6>
                <h4 class="blog-card-caption">
                    <a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h4>
                <p class="blog-card-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                <div class="ftr">
                    <div class="author">
                        <a href="#"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/5760/3840" alt="..." class="avatar img-raised"> <span>Lorem</span> </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stats"> <i class="far fa-clock"></i> 10 min </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<?php
                    //ekleme sonu







                }

            } else {
                echo "<div style=background:red> lsdkjf </div>";
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I can't see where you implemented Bootstrap4's grid columns:

> I want to show posts as 3 column.

This is how you should implement it in HTML, since I don't do Javascript:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Content</div>
  <div class="col">Content</div>
  <div class="col">Content</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap has its rows split into 12 parts, so the sum of all columns should add up to 12 otherwise something unexpected may happen but I never tried.

For the `md` thing that you added, it is supposed to target certain screen sizes, but I don't think it's necessary since you didn't specify anything about resolution.

About the numbers, they are the ratios of the columns. As you want three equal slices, you can ignore the trailing number but just remember to throw in three columns.

If my explanation seems vague, please refer to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/).